# Adding images to HBox when button clicked

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm writing simple blackjack app using JavaFX. I have a problem adding card image to HBox, when Player gets next card. I was trying to write this part of code in "get Card" button controller, but it didn't work(NullPointerException):

```
    @FXML
private void getCard() {
    playerCard = table.getNextCard();
    player.setCards(playerCard);
    Image img = new Image(TableViewController.class.getResourceAsStream(cardColor(playerCard)));
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
    showPlayerCards.getChildren().add(imgView);
}
```

cardColor() change name of the card to name of the file.

I guess, that adding image must be in "initialize" method, but I don't know, how to do this for HBox..

Comment: Which line is generating the exception?

Comment: `Image img = new Image(TableViewController.class.getResourceAsStream(cardColor(playerCard)));`

Comment: Then the path to your image is wrong.

Comment: when I'm printing it out to console, everything seems ok. Are all images must be in specyfic place? Because no matter where they were, and even after adding whole path (C:\...), this error stil occurs

Comment: [`getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) is not expecting a file system path, it is expecting a location relative to either the classpath or the current class.